# Reading a data from another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need hints. I created two tables in the database, and each table has a column called number of quantity. I formed the number of quantity into text, so the user can enter the number of quantity. I did looping through the first table and showed the result of the whole table in a grid-view by clicking the button for looping. All i need to know is, how to insert or add the number of quantity, that the user enters via a button in another table, so i can find it checked in the table's record.

Comment: its very simple, firstly, go and search on google how to insert data from C# to SqlServer (or whatever backend you got). If you get some problem doing that, then you should raise question here

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to insert whole copy of one table into other???? if you trying to insert the data of selected  row in gridview of your first table, you can use DATAKEYFIELD="TableID" to Your GRID VIEW and can access it through GRIDVIEW event (Item Command helpful), it will return you the ID of your first table, So now you got the Id means You got the data, remember the ID should be primary key in your database table